# XAML Namespace not resolved. What is this error? 

Tags: silverlight-4.0

How to fix this error?

> Error 1   XAML Namespace
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml
>   is not resolved.

```
<ResourceDictionary

  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
  xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
  xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
  xmlns:dataControls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm.Toolkit" 
  xmlns:appControls="clr-namespace:BusinessApplication1.Controls"
  xmlns:loginWindow="clr-namespace:BusinessApplication1.LoginUI"
  xmlns:dataInput="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input"

    >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a person who had a similar problem.  They resolved the problem.  Let me know if this helps:

http://www.techques.com/question/1-4250198/XAML-Namespace-http:--schemas.microsoft.com-winfx-2006-xaml-is-not-resolved

Here is the relevant quote from the article:

> (it) relates to Blend removing an attribute and breaking your XAML. It removes (or forgets to add) the mc:Ignorable="d" attribute to UserControls.